# Connect a Codegen 200XA power supply to an Asrock H61M motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I am trying to use some computer parts I found at home to build a computer for my parents. Currently I have a Codegen 200XA power supply, but it doesn't seem to have an ATX12V1 conector which I need for my Asrock H61M-DGS motherboard.

Is there anything, an adapter or some sort of hack I can use to be able to connect the motherboard and power supply? Or will I need to buy a new power supply?

Comment: Your asking if an adapter exists to convert what type of connector exactly.   I understand you want to convert it to a ATX12V1 connector.

Answer (score 0):

Real answer: You should go buy a new PSU that's properly compatible with your motherboard (ATX12V).  A low-end 400W ATX12V compatible PSU can easily be [acquired for less than US$40](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817822011).

Is there an adapter that can be had, and/or is one easy to make?  Yes.

Can you trust one?  Probably, but I've seen Molex->SATA power adapters (supplied by LG for their optical drives) melt, smolder and smoke more than once - so use appropriately gauged wire and quality soldering if you're going to make your own.

[image]

[Image source](http://www.cyberresearch.com/store/power-supplies/computer-accessories-pc-peripherals/power-cords-cables/CBL_ATX12V_1802.5.htm)